# How to fix remote: Repository not found error?

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to fix the git error:

> remote: Repository not found.
>
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user_name/xxx.git/' not found

I have tried the following fixes but not any of them fix the issue for me

1. Tried to add repository url as:
   `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user_name/xxx.git/.`
2. Tried to set my account's default identity globally with the below commands:

```
git config --global user.email "user@example.com"
git config --global user.name "username"
git config --global user.password "password"
```

3. Tried with new clone of my repository.

But still, I can't find any luck to fix this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: which command gives you the error?

Comment: Both git pull and git push.

Comment: does `git clone`  in `/tmp` succeeds?

Comment: Yes. It succeeds.

Comment: When I had tried to push my code using Github desktop, It gets pushed successfully.

Comment: can you share full command you use including the repo url so all here can reproduce?

Comment: try to modify some file in the repo you cloned in `/tmp/`, git add and commit your change, then try to push. does it work?

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` are never used for *authentication*. Setting them will not change this behavior. There is no `user.password`. You will need to investigate how your particular system *does* do authentication. This is OS-dependent, so you need to say which OS you are using.

Comment: @rok I just saw my gitconfig file can you please look into it and let me know if there is an issue because I think the issue is with my git config. It seems incomplete or credentials are missing there. 
https://pastebin.com/AktAu1xK

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to access a private repository that you are not yet a Collaborator in.